Where are the beta badges?
The private beta is over and no one has been awarded the Beta badge yet. Seeing that some users even fulfilled their commitment within the private beta itself along with being active on Meta, I dont think its possible that nobody crossed the threshold. 

Also, it appears that this badge is awarded manually globally. Can anybody confirm this?

Oh, look: 45 of 'em, hot off the forge.

These are always awarded manually ?

Yup. And... I always forget to award them.
